# IPMI get disk volumes and raid volumes (iDRAC Dell 5/6/7)

Tags: disk, ipmitool, ipmi

How to get with IPMI enabled on your Dell iDRAC 5/6/7 the disk volumes and raid volumes?
At this moment we only get the status and fan speed.

We couldn't find any documentation about the disk part.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Disk part and Raid Part are some thing done by OS.

IPMI is only used as a remote control for the BIOS. Essentially,  Processor (Board), Display, General Peripherals and monitoring Hardware used in the server chassis.
Most of the Disk based components are either from external hardware vendors or custom OS/software based solution which is difficult to be integrated and used in IPMI/KVM's firmware.

Thus the best solution for getting raid and disk volumes is from querying into OS's information.

This could eventually become a future IPMI work.